Flask API Always Predicts the Same Class When Called from PHP Script
I have developed an API using Flask to integrate a deep learning model trained on chest X-ray images for pneumonia detection. To test the connection between PHP and the Flask API, I used the Fashion MNIST model (for clothing classification) successfully, and the model was predicting classes correctly.
However, when I try to use my custom trained model for pneumonia detection (which performs very well during evaluation), I noticed that the model always predicts the class "PNEUMONIA" even when the image is in the "NORMAL" class.
Model Performance (on test set):
Test loss: 11.41 %
Test accuracy: 97.10 %
Test precision: 97.46 %
Test recall: 98.60 %
Test AUC: 98.33 %
Steps Taken:
Training: I trained the model using ResNet50 layers with additional custom layers.
Testing: I tested the model on a test set containing NORMAL and PNEUMONIA images, and it performed well.
Testing via Flask API: I tried sending images via PHP to the Flask API, but the model always predicts "PNEUMONIA".
Flask API Code:
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

app = Flask(__name__)

# Load the model
model = keras.models.load_model('path_to_your_model')

# Class names
class_names = ['NORMAL', 'PNEUMONIA']

@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    if 'image' not in request.files:
        return jsonify({'error': 'No image file provided'}), 400
    
    image = request.files['image']
    
    try:
        # Convert the image to RGB and resize it
        img = Image.open(image).convert('RGB')
        img = img.resize((224, 224))
        
        # Convert the image to an array and expand dimensions to match model input
        img_array = np.array(img) / 255.0
        img_array = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)  # Add batch dimension
        
        # Make prediction
        prediction = model.predict(img_array)
        
        # Get the predicted class
        predicted_class = class_names[int(prediction[0] > 0.5)]
        
        return jsonify({
            'prediction': predicted_class,
            'probability': float(prediction[0])
        })
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({'error': f"An error occurred: {str(e)}"}), 500

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)


PHP Code to Send Image to Flask API:
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (isset($_FILES['img']) && $_FILES['img']['error'] == 0) {
        $image = $_FILES['img']['name'];
        $image_tmp_name = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
        $folder = 'uploaded_img/';
        $image_folder = $folder . $image;
        
        if (!is_dir($folder)) {
            mkdir($folder, 0777, true);
        }
        
        if (move_uploaded_file($image_tmp_name, $image_folder)) {
            $url = 'http://localhost:5000/predict';
            $cfile = new CURLFile($image_folder, 'image/jpeg', $image);
            $data = array('image' => $cfile);
            
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            
            if ($response === false) {
                echo "Error in prediction!";
            } else {
                $result = json_decode($response, true);
                echo "Prediction: " . $result['prediction'];
            }
        }
    }
}
?>


Issue: Despite the model working well when tested locally with good performance metrics on NORMAL and PNEUMONIA images, when I test it through the Flask API (via PHP), the model always predicts "PNEUMONIA", even when the image is from the "NORMAL" class.
Is there any issue with the way I'm sending the image or how the Flask API is processing it?

Try to find out if the image being sent to php is the exact one you want. Use some tool like Burp Suite or any other web proxy that you like. I've got a feeling that the image sent by PHP is the same image each time (or the image content is empty).

I'm sure it'd be better if you could provide a reproducible code that people can try on their local environments so we could help.

What is the reason why you have been using PHP as a broker between the client and Flask? Why not use Flask directly?
But, maybe you need to rename the files when they are moved between folders in the PHP script, for example, if you receive an image called test1.jpg you could try renaming the file by adding some of the timestamp then the file name finally called test1-12123434.png the point is to avoid the probable cache problems with the files at the PHP server

i use PHP because it's a web app contain another serveries and connection between users

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
